# Diameter - Encoding of IPAddress type and Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, diameter-protocol

I was looking at some Diameter traces in Wireshark from one of my tests and noticed that the Framed-IP-Address AVP was encoded incorrectly. The type of this AVP in Wireshark Diameter dictionary is :

```
<avp name="Framed-IP-Address" code="8" mandatory="must" protected="may" may-encrypt="yes" vendor-bit="mustnot">
    <type type-name="IPAddress"/>
</avp>
```

Here is the snippet of Framed-IP-Address AVP from Wireshark:

[image: Framed-IP-Address]

At the same time, the Host-IP-Address AVP (in CEA) which is also encoded similar to the Framed-IP-Address AVP does not show any error and the AVP is also defined as of type IPAddress in the Wireshark dictionary.

```
<avp name="Host-IP-Address" code="257" mandatory="must" protected="may" may-encrypt="no" vendor-bit="mustnot">
    <type type-name="IPAddress"/>
</avp>
```

Here is the snippet of Host-IP-Address from Wireshark:

[image: Host-IP-Address]

I know that there is something wrong in my encoding, but I am not able to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

M bit missing in AVP flags.
I think that is the root cause.